# Impedir de fechar janela modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber se é possivel impedir de fechar a janela modal do `Bootstrap` ao atualizar a página. Como lidamos com diversos tipos de usuários, preciso que isso ocorra para que eu possa mudar o status do `banco de dados`. Com o código abaixo, consegui impedir que os usuários fechem a janela clicando fora dele:

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

Porém preciso impedir também que a janela feche ao apertar a tecla `F5`.

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Não é possível "mantê-la" aberta porque ao apertar F5 uma nova página é "gerada". O que pode tentar fazer é salvar a informação de que o modal está aberto para quando a página for carregada mais uma vez, exibir automaticamente ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há como impedir de fechar o navegador ou atualizar a página, mas tem como enviar ao usuário uma janela de confirmação, por exemplo:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Você não salvou a sua tarefa, gostaria mesmo de sair?";
};
```

O problema é que assim a pergunta vai executar em qualquer situação, então você pode verificar se a janela do bootstrap é visivel antes de lançar a confirmação:

Desta maneira a confirmação só aparece se a janela modal estiver aberta:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
   if ($("#myModal").is(":visible")) {
       return "Você não salvou a sua tarefa, gostaria mesmo de sair?";
   }
});
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo simples</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
       if ($("#myModal").is(":visible")) {
           return "Você não salvou a sua tarefa, gostaria mesmo de sair?";
       }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Ver janela
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo. Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas sou leigo em Jquery. Nesse caso coloco antes da tag body, certo? Quando coloquei, não funcionou.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Olha o exemplo que adicionei, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. Funcionou perfeitamente. Abraço!